# UUID and Drive Cloning

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning, mount, uuid

When cloning a drive (using `dd`), will the UUID's for each partition change, or are they hardware specific? or does cloning it preserve the UUID as well?

What happen if a system detected two devices with the same UUID?

Comment: Why not just try it yourself and see if they change?

Comment: 32gb USB to USB across a VM.... :'(

Comment: If you just want to test if DD changes UUID's or not, then why not just use a small test source disk/partition with little data on it, locally?

Comment: And the last part is still valid. If the UUID stays the same, how the the system deal with multiple of the same UUID? I guess that works...

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/156063/why-cant-mint-boot-my-cloned-ubuntu-partition-uuid-issue

Comment: I failed to find this in my initial search. Found my answer, and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

UUIDs are not hardware-specific but stored in the partition's filesystem. That means cloning a disk or partition with `dd` will result in the same UUID.

You can assign a new UUID by using:

- `tune2fs -U random <device>` (ext2/ext3/ext4)
- `xfs_admin -U generate <device>` (xfs)
- `reiserfstune -u $(uuidgen) <device>` (reiserfs)
- `mkswap -U $(uuidgen) <device>` (swap)

Having duplicated UUIDs doesn't necessarily lead to errors. However booting and mounting a device by UUID will become ambiguous and may lead to the wrong device being used.

Comment: "However booting and mounting a device by UUID will become ambiguous and may lead to the wrong device being used." Yes. This can become really dangerous when a cloned disk is used as backup. You need to double check that /home is really the disk you think it is. A "backup" done in the wrong direction can wipe out data from both disks.

Comment: What would you run to assign a new UUID to a vfat filesystem like a /boot/efi partition?